# C# How to avoid duplicate code with interfaces where objects have the same behaviour

Tags: c#, interfaces

So a simple example i have:

```
public interface IFollow{
    Transform Target {get;}
    void LateUpdate();
}

public A : Monobehaviour , IFollow {

   public Transform Target {get; set;}
   public void LateUpdate(){
      //follow the target
   }
}

public B : Monobehaviour , IFollow {

   public Transform Target {get; set;}
   public void LateUpdate(){
      //follow the target [duplicate code as seen in A]
}
```

When you have lots of different objects that follow a target with the same logic the implemented interface  forces you to write a lot of duplicate code.

It also doesn't make much sense to do it via a base class since not all objects will follow.

What's a cleaner way to do this without so much duplication ?

Encase any one wondered, `Monobehaviour` is a Unity3D thing, though not overly relevant to the question but thought i'd mention it.

Comment: There's not enough information in your question to determine why you have a lot of code duplication.

Comment: Because every object that implements the interface will all have identical LateUpdate follow logic. I'm literally copy pasting the follow logic to each class that requires it. Its kinda silly. Not sure why you're confused by that.

Comment: Then why aren't you using a base class to capture the common functionality?  You can't have it both ways.  Either you use a base class and put the common functionality there even though some of it won't be used, or you live with the duplication.  Perhaps work with two or three more specific base classes?

Comment: Because if its in the base class then all objects follow but i said in the question only some do. An interface seems more logical to me. Thats entirely why i'm asking for advice here. Because i don't know the best approach.

Also what would the base class even be when it would only have a follow behaviour in it? Doesn't feel like an `is an` setup for a base class then.

Comment: Composition, then.  The best approach is the one that most effectively meets your needs.

Comment: you can just make a `virtual` method in the base class. If you need a particular implementation in a subclass, you can override it and change its functionality.

Comment: `It also doesn't make much sense to do it via a base class since not all objects will follow.` Who said that all objects (I assume you mean classes) will inherit the base class? Inheritance isn't the best option here (as per the other answers/comment), but even if it were, you're not forced to implement it across the board.

Comment: @Flater from what i've learnt up to now, inheriting a base class is frequently an `is a` relationship. But a follow is more like a `does a` behaviour, so my initial thought was an interface.

Eg does it make sense to have `NPC : FollowBehaviour` vs `SomeMonster : NPC , IFollowBehaviour` to me it seems the latter is more flexible and more logical.

Comment: @WDUK Whay you say isn't wrong, but it's not what I was responding to. If you were to use inheritance here, there's nothing to suggest that _all_ classes need to derive from that same follower class. You implied as much in your argument as to why inheritance wouldn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two options:

- Implement in a(n) (abstract) base class
- Implement in a helper adapter

Make a base class, or an abstract base class that implements the common behavior, and inherit from that. This way your code lives in one place and isn't duplicated.

If a base class doesn't work for some reason, you could put the code into a adapter (or strategy) object that each class uses to implement the behavior, again moving the duplicated code to one place.

Comment: Do you have an example for the adaptor setup so i understand what you mean ?

Comment: the [adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) pattern is a _has a_ relationship. You would make a class like Follower : IFollow that has an implementation that can be used to implement IFollow by wrapper/passthrough to the adapter or [strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) (a very similar pattern)

Comment: Base classes are appropriate in some cases, but do need to be considered carefully, especially in languages without multiple inheritence.  There is a maxim that says [favour composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

Answer (score 3):

You can first extract the common behavior(s) into simple classes which only implement `IFollow`:

```
public sealed class FollowTarget : IFollow
{
    public Transform Target {get; set;}
    public void LateUpdate() { //follow the target }
}

public sealed class FollowSomethingElse : IFollow
{
    public Transform Target {get; set;}
    public void LateUpdate() { //follow something else }
}
```

Then use the required implementation in `A`, `B`, `C`:

```
public sealed A : Monobehaviour , IFollow {
    private readonly IFollow _follow;
    public A() => _follow = new FollowTarget();
    public Transform Target {get => _follow.Target; set => _follow.Target = value; }
    public void LateUpdate() => _follow.LateUpdate();
}

public sealed B : Monobehaviour , IFollow {
    private readonly IFollow _follow;
    public B() => _follow = new FollowTarget();
    public Transform Target {get => _follow.Target; set => _follow.Target = value; }
    public void LateUpdate() => _follow.LateUpdate();
}

public sealed C : Monobehaviour , IFollow {
    private readonly IFollow _follow;
    public C() => _follow = new FollowSomethingElse();
    public Transform Target {get => _follow.Target; set => _follow.Target = value; }
    public void LateUpdate() => _follow.LateUpdate();
}
```

Then at this point you *may* see that `A`/`C` or `B`/`C` share the same implementation except that you don't instanciate the same `_follow`. In this case you can require an `IFollow` in the constructor and refactor (simplify) your code like this:

```
public sealed AorC : Monobehaviour , IFollow {
    private readonly IFollow _follow;
    public AorC(IFollow follow) => _follow = follow;
    public Transform Target {get => _follow.Target; set => _follow.Target = value; }
    public void LateUpdate() => _follow.LateUpdate();
}

public sealed B : Monobehaviour , IFollow {
    private readonly IFollow _follow;
    public B() => _follow = new FollowTarget();
    public Transform Target {get => _follow.Target; set => _follow.Target = value; }
    public void LateUpdate() => _follow.LateUpdate();
}
```

Usage beeing

```
var a = new AorC(new FollowTarget()); 
var c = new AorC(new FollowSomethingElse());
```

This approach is usually named [Decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) and is a specialized form of composition which fosters a more composable code.

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the method (but not the interface) from the class, and move the logic to an extension method:

```
public interface IFollow
{
    Transform Target {get;}
}

static public class ExtensionMethods
{
     static public void LateUpdate<T>(this T source) where T : IFollow
     {
         var target = source.Target; //Works, due to the type constraint
         //Add code to follow the target here
     }
}

public A : Monobehaviour , IFollow
{
    public Transform Target {get; set;}
}

public B : Monobehaviour , IFollow
{
    public Transform Target {get; set;}
}
```

You'd still call it exactly the same way as before, only you need to remember to include the namespace of your extension method (if it is different):

```
A a = new A();
a.LateUpdate();
```

You could also combine these methods; for example, you could leave `LateUpdate()` in the interface, but write the implementation as a pass-through that only calls the extension method behind the scenes. This would be valuable if you need the method in the interface for some reason.

Comment: What if LateUpdate has arguements i'm not sure of the syntax in that case? Some times it passes a delta time for example `LateUpdate(Timer deltaTime)`;

Comment: the extension method cant do everything a method could do

Comment: OP said that "not all objects follows", which is his counterpoint to a base class, but an extension method would automatically apply to everything `IFollow`. Not exactly an improvement over a base class implementation. The "pass-through" suggestion is also questionable. If you put it in the interface, you'll be forced to implement it in every class, or use a base class anyway, and it will also cause you some confusion (now you have multiple methods matching the `IFollow.LateUpdate()` call, even if only the proper class method will ever be called).

Comment: @BgrWorker I interpret the requirement as "allow a series of classes to expose `IFollow` without requiring duplicate implementation of `LastUpdate()`" which I believe this answer achieves. I wouldn't recommend adopting this as a common pattern, but maybe in a corner case it can help. The pass-through suggestion helps when the implementation is non-trivial or if there are several classes that expose `IFollow` and keeping their code in sync would be a chore..

Answer (score 1):

C# 8 now supports default interfaces. So you could write it like this:

```
public interface IFollow
{
    Transform Target { get; }
    public void LateUpdate() {
        Console.WriteLine("Follow the target");
    }
}

public class A : Monobehaviour, IFollow
{
    public Transform Target { get; set; }       
}

public class B : Monobehaviour, IFollow
{

    public Transform Target { get; set; }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would move the code to another component that you call.

```
public class RepeatingCode : MonoBehaviour
{
    void RepeatThis() { }
}
```

```
public A : Monobehaviour, IFollow {

   public Transform Target {get; set;}
   private RepeatingCode Repeating;

   void Awake() => Repeating = GetComponent<RepeatingCode>();

   public void LateUpdate()
   {
      Repeating.RepeatThis();
   }
}

public B : Monobehaviour, IFollow {

   public Transform Target {get; set;}
   public RepeatingCode Repeating; // Assigned using Inspector

   public void LateUpdate()
   {
      Repeating.RepeatThis();
   }
}
```